# Is every "normal" use of user-defined literals undefined behavior?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

User defined literals *must* start with an underscore.

This is a more or less universally well-known rule that you can find on every layman-worded site talking about user literals. It is also a rule which I (and possibly others?) have been blatantly ignoring ever since on a "what a bullshit" base. Now of course, that's strictly not correct. In the strictest sense, this uses a reserved identifier, and thus invokes Undefined Behavior (although you don't get as much as a shrug from the compiler, practically).

So, pondering whether I should continue to deliberately ignore that (in my opinion useless) part of the standard or not, I decided to look at what's actually written. Because, you know, what does it matter what *everybody knows*. What matters is what's written in the standard.

`[over.literal]` states that "some" literal suffix identifiers are reserved, linking to `[usrlit.suffix]`. The latter states that **all** are reserved, except those that start with an underscore. OK, so that's pretty much exactly what we already knew, explicitly written (or rather, written backwards).

Also, `[over.literal]` contains a *Note* which hints to an obvious but troubling thing:

> except for the constraints described above, they are ordinary namespace-scope functions and function templates

Well, sure they are. Nowhere does it say that they aren't, so what else would you expect them to be.

But wait a moment. `[lex.name]` explicitly states that each identifier that begins with an underscore **in the global namespace** is reserved.

Now, a literal operator usually, unless you explicitly put it into a namespace (which, I believe nobody does!?) is very much in the global namespace. So, the name, which *must* begin with an underscore, is reserved. There is no mention of a special exception. So, every name (with underscore, or without) is a reserved name.

Are you indeed expected to put user defined literals into a namespace because the "normal" usage (underscore or not) is using a reserved name?

Comment: I wonder if UDL suffixes count as an identifiers.

Comment: FWIW your code should be in a namespace and if you follow that you are safe.

Comment: @NathanOliver-ReinstateMonica: How would I even use that literal then? Let's say I've put, whatever, say... `_km` (for kilometers) it in the namespace `udl`. Then a literal for 5km looks like... `5udl::_km`?

Comment: @NathanOliver-ReinstateMonica That’s what I thought … but that’s not true, see my answer.

Comment: @Damon `using udl::operator ""_km`, or `using namespace udl`.

Comment: @Damon That is what `using` statements are for.  In the scope where you need to use the literal, have a using statement that imports it.

Comment: @KonradRudolph: Well, certainly, the rule exists for the same reason why other identifiers are reserved. And of course, from the implementor's point of view, it makes sense, too.  It's just that my personal point of view is a different one (user's point of view). From that POV it causes a major inconvenience with very little (in fact, zero) gains for features that don't exist or aren't implemented for years to go (and if they existed I'd likely not use them anyway). But how I personally feel about it is probably irrelevant for the question whether it's legal per the standard.

Answer (score 6):

Yes: the combination of forbidding the use of `_` as the start of a global identifier coupled with requiring non-standard UDLs to start with `_` means that you can't put them in the global namespace. But you shouldn't be dirtying up the global namespace with stuff, *especially* UDLs, so that shouldn't be much of a problem.

The traditional idiom, as used by the standard, is to put UDLs in a `literals` namespace (and if you have different sets of UDLs, then you put them in different `inline namespaces` below that namespace). That `literals` namespace is typically underneath your main one. When you want to use a particular set of UDLs, you invoke `using namespace my_namespace::literals` or whichever sub-namespace contains your literal set of choice.

This is important because UDLs tend to be *heavily* abbreviated. The standard for example uses `s` for `std::string`, but also for `std::chrono::duration` of seconds. While they do apply to different kinds of literals (`s` applied to a string is a string, while `s` applied to a number is a duration), it can sometimes be confusing to read code that uses abbreviated literals. So you shouldn't throw literals at all users of your library; they should opt-in to using them.

By using different namespaces for these (`std::literals::string_literals` and `std::literals::chrono_literals`), the user can be up-front about which sets of literals they want in which parts of code.

Comment: Unfortunately this answer doesn’t seem to address the validity of `_Foo` suffixes, which were omitted from the question but are rather problematic.

Comment: _the combination of forbidding the use of `_` as the start of a global identifier coupled with requiring non-standard UDLs to start with `_` means that you can't put them in the global namespace_ Why? _literal-operator-id_ declaration doesn't introduce its _identifier_ into its scope. You can easily check it with `int operator"" _xxx(unsigned long long) { return 0; }

auto i = _xxx(0); // ERROR: _xxx was not declared`

Comment: @LanguageLawyer: Because the standard says so. You may not think it is necessary, but the standard is very clear about this: "Each identifier that begins with an underscore is reserved to the implementation for use as a name in
the global namespace." UDLs put names in the global namespace.

Comment: Do you know what does «used as a name» mean?

Comment: _UDLs put names in the global namespace_ And the name is `operator"" _xxx`, not `_xxx`.

Answer (score 5):

> Is every “normal” use of user-defined literals undefined behavior?

Clearly not.

The following is the *idiomatic* (and thus definitely “normal”) use of UDLs, and it’s well-defined according to the rule you’ve just listed:

```
namespace si {
    struct metre { … };

    constexpr metre operator ""_m(long double value) { return metre{value}; }
}
```

You’ve listed problematic cases and I agree with your assessment about their validity but they’re easily avoided in idiomatic C++ code so I don’t entirely see the problem with the current wording, even if it was potentially accidental.

According to the example in [over.literal]/8, we can even use capital letters after the underscore:

> ```
> float operator ""E(const char*);    // error: reserved literal suffix (20.5.4.3.5, 5.13.8)
> double operator""_Bq(long double);  // OK: does not use the reserved identifier _Bq (5.10)
> double operator"" _Bq(long double); // uses the reserved identifier _Bq (5.10)
> ```

The only problematic thing thus seems to be the fact that the standard makes the whitespace between `""` and the UDL name significant.

Comment: Good catch, I didn't even think about capital-letter SI units.

Comment: The standard contains an example that shows that `operator""_Bq` is ok (which means `operator""_K` is also ok). The trick is to omit the space between `""` and the suffix. See C++17 [over.literal]/8.

Comment: @Brian I hate it when examples are the only source of normative wording. Great find. And the fact that they decided to make this whitespace significant is even more messed up. Either way, I’ve fixed my answer.

Comment: It's not that the example is the only source. Rather, this follows from the fact that a *user-defined-string-literal* is a single preprocessing token. That being said, the example does clarify the intent, plus I never would have realized this if it weren't for the example.

Comment: @Brian "...  a _user-defined-string-literal_ is a single preprocessing token". Could you clarify where can I find this in the Standard?

Comment: @Belloc C++17 5.4 ([lex.pptoken])

Comment: @Belloc There are two grammar productions for *literal-operator-id*. Note that `""_Bq2` is a *user-defined-string-literal*, a single preprocessing token. Whereas `"" _Bq2` is a *string-literal* followed by an *identifier*. Both are valid syntax. But in the latter case, a reserved identifier is present, which violates the rules on reserved names.

Comment: @Brian I thought I had understood your [comment above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59180353/is-every-normal-use-of-user-defined-literals-undefined-behavior/59181016#comment104583607_59180594), but I still have problems with the example in [\[over.literal\]/8](http://eel.is/c++draft/over.literal#8). Please, see [this snippet](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d58cd0baff1f2f51) in Coliru.

Comment: @Brian Now I can see what you mean. That's really tricky. I suppose the rule being violated in my example is [\[lex.name\]/(3.1)](http://eel.is/c++draft/lex.name#3.1). Is that correct?

Comment: @Belloc Yes. It is very tricky and one would never guess this if it had not been an explicit example.

Comment: @Brian Congratulations. I think I would never guess this myself even with the example. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 5):

This is a good question, and I'm not sure about the answer, but I think the answer is "no, it's not UB" based on a particular reading of the standard.

[lex.name]/3.2 reads:

> Each identifier that begins with an underscore is reserved to the implementation for use as a name in the global namespace.

Now, clearly, the restriction "as a name in the global namespace" should be read as applying to the entire rule, not just to how the implementation may use the name. That is, its meaning is not

"each identifier that begins with an underscore is reserved to the implementation, AND the implementation may use such identifiers as names in the global namespace"

but rather,

"the use of any identifier that begins with an underscore as a name in the global namespace is reserved to the implementation".

(If we believed the first interpretation, then it would mean that no one could declare a function called `my_namespace::_foo`, for example.)

Under the second interpretation, something like a global declaration of `operator""_foo` (in the global scope) is legal, because such a declaration does not use `_foo` as a name. Rather, the identifier is just a part of the actual name, which is `operator""_foo` (which does *not* start with an underscore).

Comment: I was going to go with a similar interpretation. Considering one can define a function like `void operator+(foo, bar)`, where clearly the function name is not an identifier, but it is a name. Same goes for `operator "" _foo` being the name in our case.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, defining your own user defined literal in the global namespace results in an ill-formed program.

I haven't run into this myself, because I try to follow the rule:

Don't put anything (besides `main`, namespaces, and `extern "C"` stuff for ABI stability) in the global namespace.

```
namespace Mine {
  struct meter { double value; };
  inline namespace literals {
    meter operator ""_m( double v ) { return {v}; }
  }
}

int main() {
  using namespace Mine::literals;
  std::cout << 15_m.value << "\n";
}
```

This also means you cannot use `_CAPS` as your literal name, even in a namespace.

Inline namespaces called `literals` is a great way to package up your user defined literal operators.  They can be imported where you want to use it without having to name exactly which literals you want, or if you import the entire namespace you also get the literals.

This follows how the `std` library handles literals as well, so should be familiar to users of your code.

Answer (score 0):

Given the literal with suffix `_X`, [the grammar calls `_X` an "identifier"](http://eel.is/c++draft/lex.ext#nt:ud-suffix).

So, yes: the standard has, presumably inadvertently, made it impossible to create a UDT at global scope, or UDTs that start with a capital letter, in a well-defined program. (Note that the former is not something you generally want to do anyway!)

This cannot be resolved editorially: the names of user-defined literals would have to have their own lexical "namespace" that prevented clashes with (for example) names of implementation-provided functions. In my opinion, though, it would have been nice for there to be a non-normative note somewhere, pointing out the consequences of these rules and pointing out that they are deliberate.

Comment: Even with an exception won't an implementation defined `int _x(int);` (in global) cause a compilation error?

Comment: Potentially interesting further reading: [CWG 1882](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1882)

Comment: @RichardCritten What do you mean?

Comment: I understood: _"...arguably should have an exemption..."_ to indicate that user defined operators of the form `_x` should be exempt from  `[lex.name]`.  If I have misunderstood then what follows next is __rubbish__.  If the implementation had already declared a function `int _x(int);` in global scope (reserved name so ok), then a user declared `long double operator "" _x(long double);` (for example) would get a compilation error.

Comment: I don't see how an exemption can cure this issue.

Comment: @RichardCritten Granted, I suppose any such exemption would have to be accompanied by changes in the lookup rules, lol

Comment: Yup the nice _simple_ lookup rules.

Comment: @RichardCritten Indeed. I have made an edit (attribution in rev history)