# Reserved Names & User Literals

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, user-defined-literals

The C++ Standard reserves names beginning with an underscore followed by a capital letter in all scopes.

Does this apply to user literal operators?

e.g.

```
int _MyInt; // reserved, violation

template < char... >
auto operator "" _MyInt ( ); // reserved???
```

Comment: Personally, I'd just stay on the safe side and stick to lower-case.

Comment: If that's allowed, it looks like the C++ implementation should avoid defining any macros starting with underscore + capital letter in the standard libraries (?)

Comment: @chi They can always `#undef` I suppose

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is every "normal" use of user-defined literals undefined behavior?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59180353/is-every-normal-use-of-user-defined-literals-undefined-behavior)

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings As the comment on an answer to the question you posted says, cases like `_Foo` are not covered, which is what this question is asking.

Comment: Given that clang forbids `template < char... > auto operator "" _ExtInt ( );`, I'd say it does apply in practice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it allows the use of an underscore followed by a capital letter (which is otherwise a reserved identifier).

[Source](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/user_literal)

I've only found an example, not a formal paragraph, in the standard supporting the above:

[[over.literal]](http://eel.is/c++draft/over.literal#8)

```
double operator""_Bq(long double);    // OK: does not use the reserved identifier _­Bq
double operator"" _Bq(long double);   // uses the reserved identifier _­Bq
```

So, as long as you don't put a space between `""` and `_Ud` it's ok - according to the example that is.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215268/discussion-on-answer-by-ted-lyngmo-reserved-names-user-literals).